# Undefined Property ИмяКонтроллера::$имяМетода

Tags: php, ооп, mvc

Пробую писать свою MVC-шку. При попытке сделать вызов метода по такому принципу 
**$controllerObject->$methodName** выдаёт ошибку

```
Notice: Undefined property: NewsController::$index in C:\Users\admin\PhpstormProjects\jolyMVC\App\Components\Router.php on line 42
```

КОД

```
$uri = $this->getURI();
        foreach ($this->routes as $uriPattern => $path) {
            if (preg_match("~$uriPattern~", $uri)) {
                $segments = explode('@', $path);

                $controllerName = array_shift($segments);
                $methodName = array_shift($segments);
                echo $methodName;
                $controllerFile = ROOT."/controllers/".$controllerName.".php";
                if (file_exists($controllerFile)) {
                    require_once($controllerFile);
                }
                $controllerObject = new $controllerName;
                $result = $controllerObject->$methodName;

                if ($result != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Как мне убрать $ у метода?

Comment: `$methodName()`, надеюсь понятно что если это метод - то его надо вызывать с помощью скобок?

Comment: @u_mulder точно. спасибо. Невнимательность подвела

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$methodName нужно было заменить на $methodName()

Спасибо пользователю @**u_mulder** за быстрый и верный ответ!